# HandlebarsJS White Space in Precompiled Templates

Tags: javascript, html, handlebars.js

I'm in the process of migrating one of my projects to use HandlebarsJS templates instead of underscore templates and I have come across a very strange issue.

I'm using precompiled templates and everywhere i'm appending rendered templates to the DOM i'm getting an empty text element appended as well which is causing layout issues with gaps rendering in place of them

Looking at the chrome dev console shows the following markup of 3 templates appended to a div:

```
> <div>
      ""
      <div><!--content --></div>
      ""
      <div><!--content --></div>
      ""
      <div><!--content --></div>
  </div>
```

When dumping the parent div HTML to the javascript console there aren't any spaces at all, it's simply:

```
<div><!--content --></div><div><!--content --></div><div><!--content --></div>
```

Comment: What do the templates look like? How are you appending them? Perhaps a quick example on jsfiddle.net or jsbin.com would help.

Comment: Good idea: it's a bit contrived as I had to rework the code to work jsfiddle and copy in the relevant library code (my code is at the bottom) - http://jsfiddle.net/abJMU/1/ when it has run, inspect the output HTML and you will see exactly what I mean with the empty text nodes being appended prior to each template

Comment: (1) You can use the *External Resources* panel to import `handlebars.js` (or start with http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/w2wyU/) (2) What do the templates look like? I doubt precompiling has anything to do with this.

Comment: Nice, external resources work better! It would appear the problem is actually precompilation, I've updated the jsfiddle with an inline template (exactly the same as used for precompiled version) and it doesn't add the space! Have a look - [jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/w2wyU/5/)

Comment: Ok I've found the problem, handlebars is adding a \ufeff character to the beginning of the precompiled html, it doesn't show in Visual Studio or any of the browser extensions but fortunately it does show in JSFiddle, you can see the red dot that represents the character in the last jsfiddle example. So I just need to strip it out!

Comment: The \ufeff looks like a BOM (Byte Order Marker). I use precompiled Handlebars templates in a few projects and I don't think I've ever seen that in my compiled templates. Interesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok this is now resolved, as per the comments on the original question the issue was a \ufeff character which was being added during precompilation, my IDE and developer browser extensions don't display the character even with visible white-space options enabled.

To resolve the issue i updated my template appending code to

```
$container.append(template({ *data* }).replace(/\ufeff/, ''));
```